# Laravels object_get() helper broken in PHP7

Tags: laravel-4, php-7, php-7.2

We are working on an older Laravel 4.2 project and the new environment it is going on requires PHP7.  We are trying to get this working, but we notice that the object_get() helper does not seem to work properly.  Is there anything in this code that would not work from PHP 5.6 to 7?

```
function object_get($object, $key, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key) || trim($key) == '') return $object;

        foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment)
        {
            if ( ! is_object($object) || ! isset($object->{$segment}))
            {
                return value($default);
            }

            $object = $object->{$segment};
        }

        return $object;
    }
```